# How to include an integer value to a spinner array

Tags: java, android

So i've got 2 spinners, 1st allows the user to select the TYPE of food, which then populates the 2nd spinner with the option for that TYPE. (Breakfast = Fruit, Lunch = Sandwich etc).

I'm looking to add the integer values (e.g. apple 62 kcalories per 100grams) behind these for a calculation of: Selected food calories (int per 100 grams) multiplied by weight inputted into a editText (id food_Grams).

So I want each item of food in the 2nd spinner to have an integer value that will be used in a calculation for a running total of calories added. How would I do this in the code provided?

```
 public class ActivityAdd extends MainActivity {

public Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
public Button btnSubmit;
boolean app_started = true;


protected void onCreate(Bundle x) {

    super.onCreate(x);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityadd);

    chooseCategory();
    chooseBreakfast();
    chooseLunch();
    chooseDinner();
    chooseSnack();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

}

public void chooseCategory() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.foodtype);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.foodtype, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(catAdapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnSelectedListener());
}

private void chooseBreakfast() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist.add("Cereal");
    planlist.add("Porrige");
    planlist.add("Fruit");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
    planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
}

private void chooseLunch() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist1.add("Sandwich");
    planlist1.add("Omelette");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist1);
    planAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
}

private void chooseDinner() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist2.add("Pizza");
    planlist2.add("Pasta");
    planlist2.add("Pie");
    planlist2.add("Fish");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist2);
    planAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter3);
}

private void chooseSnack() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist2.add("Crisps");
    planlist2.add("Biscuit");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist2);
    planAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter3);
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

// get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.foodtype);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityAdd.this,
                    "OnClickListener : " +
                            "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                            "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}

public class planOnSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        if (!app_started) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            if (pos == 0) {
                chooseBreakfast();
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                chooseLunch();
            } else if (pos == 2) {
                chooseDinner();
            } else if (pos == 3) {
                chooseSnack();
            }

        }
        app_started = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think your question is very broad. Maybe you can isolate just the a single spinner? Anyways, at a high level the answer to your question is that you create an adapter that knows how to translate the position to a integer and display it in a view.

Comment: Could you show an example of this?